# Elastic index rollover at inconsistent docs count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created ILM policy with following configuration :

```
{
    "policy": {
        "phases": {
            "hot": {
                "actions": {
                    "rollover": {
                        "max_docs": 15000
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "min_age": "1d",
                "actions": {
                    "delete": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `index_template` for matching indices.

Now when I bootstrap the index with initial index lets say `<index-name>-000001` then the expectation is to rollover the index once `docs.count` reaches to 15000.
The rollover is happening but at random docs.count and I'm not sure why it is happening.

[image]

Also docs.count is not updating I will have to manually hit refresh API, then docs count is getting updated at `/_cat/indices`. Please let me know what is wrong in the config. Did I missing anything?

Comment: What [refresh_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting) do you have in the index template?

Comment: I haven't set it explicitly, however I can see my index "refresh_interval": "1s" is set

Comment: Could you please run `GET /INDEX-000001/_ilm/explain` for one of your indices?

Comment: @ilvar `refresh_interval` solved my problem. I changed it to 10s worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `refresh_interval`.

By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second, but only on indices that have received one search request or more in the last 30 seconds.
My indices were not getting search request so couldn't update the indices.
I changed the default setting, I added  `"refresh_interval":"10s"` in my index template which inherited into my newly created index.

Also I changed the `_cluster/setting` poll interval to 1 minute for testing and it worked!